# Port forwarding a Node http server through Asus router. Unable to connect

Tags: node.js, http, https, ip, ip-address

I am trying to set up a simple Node server on my Raspberry Pi 4 that is accessible on the internet.

So far, I am able to run a Node server that is accessible on all computers on the router through `http://192.168.1.56:3000` but I want this website accessible outside of the router.

I have enabled port forwarding on my router (**ASUS RT-AC68U**, Firmware version: 3.0.0.4.384_81049) as shown:
[image: port forwarding settings]

However, I am unable to connect from outside the router.

I found my public WAN IP address using https://whatismyipaddress.com/
(Let's call it 12.345.678.900).

But connecting to http://12.345.678.900:3000 does not load my website. I have also tried different combinations of https and different port numbers with no luck.

Weirdly, even after disabling port forwarding on the router, going to
https://12.345.678.900 in Chrome it displays the following message

> **This site can’t provide a secure connection**
>
> 12.345.678.900 uses an unsupported protocol.
>
> `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

Internet explorer also changes its message to "Cannot securely connect to this page" so there seems to be something already hosted on my ip address?

Since this is true when I have disabled port forwarding, is this something to do with my ISP?

I also used the `wget https://12.345.678.900` command and it outputs

```
Connecting to 12.345.678.900:443... connected.
GnuTLS: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
GnuTLS: received alert [40]: Handshake failed
Unable to establis SSL connection.
```

So, it seems to be connecting to something on port 443?

Are there any other settings/things I should check?

I've looked through other threads on here but no solutions were able to help.

**Edit:**
Further research using [yougetsignal](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) shows both ports 53 and 443 are open. So is this a router config issue?

Comment: this isn't really a software problem - but that said, you might not be able to test the WAN side of your setup from inside your own network.  Can others reach that IP and port?

Comment: @Joe I've tested the connection using mobile data on my phone with the same results. No connection for port 3000 and unsupported protocol for https

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this web article](https://customer.cradlepoint.com/s/article/NCOS-How-to-determine-if-you-have-a-publicly-routable-IP-address), it seems it is indeed a hardware issue due to not having a publicly routable IP address.